# Design patterns exercise in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Hi
I have an assignment to teach a team the subject of design principle. As a final exercise to this mini course, I thought to give them an exercise in design pattern, in Java.
My idea is to give them a code written badly, and they should refactor it using several design patterns. I didn't find anything similar to that in my search (both in the web and in stack overflow).

Any references to something similar to what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: Any of the code on http://www.roseindia.net should do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the best sites out there :   http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/catalog.html

They basically show you code, and then the re-factored code.  Its not going to be one big hopping pile of crap, but you can take an aggregate a couple and aggregate them together to form some ugly code, and then do the same to show the solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can check this book "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code" of Martin Fowler. It contains examples of "smell" coding and provide solution to refactor it.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Refactoring to Patterns]

This has alot of code filling the bill.  The author, Joshua Kerievsky, is also the founder of [Industrial Logic](https://www.industriallogic.com/), which has (as Nix noted in his response) good material on this topic, drawn from and augmenting this book.

Comment: +1 I meant to mention the book but forgot, "refactoring to patterns" is an amazing book..